# Identifying the sql server thread(query) causing high CPU usage

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, cpu-usage

I have MSSQLSERVER database.Since yesterday,it is causing high CPU usage around 98%-99% usage.I got Performance Monitor which can help in this.Can any one help in debugging the high usage issue using Performance Monitor.
Any other way is also welcome.
Thanx in advance.